# Javascript to display local image

Tags: javascript, replace, server, ads, adsense

I have a local network with 200 clients and I want to display ads on every website.My idea is this.
The router `192.168.1.1` redirects `*.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js` to `http://192.168.1.1/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js`

On my webserver the `adsbygoogle.js` has

```
var f = new Image();
f.src = "a.jpg";
if(document.images)
{
document.images.f.src = newImage.src;
}
```

`f.src` is found in the original `adsbygoogle.js`.
This should display my image instead of google ads on every website that is accessed from LAN but instead I get a blank page.
I'm also hosting revive adserver but had no luck with it.
How do i display my image from the hosted `adsbygoogle.js` to the LAN?

Comment: `f.src` doesn't seem to be in your DOM. Maybe you want to do `newImage.src = "a.jpg"`?

Comment: there has to be a better way to deliver ads than hijacking google...

Answer (score 0):

The path `a.jpg` will be relative to the site the script is included on. So if the visitor is at `http://sitename.example/`, your script will attempt to link to an image at `http://sitename.example/a.jpg`.

Instead, link absolutely to where the image is hosted. If it's on `http://192.168.1.1/`, then you should specify `http://192.168.1.1/a.jpg` in the JS file.